# How can I find how many times a number appears in a list without counting negatives?

Tags: python, list

I want to know how many times the number 3 appears in the following:

```
3,3,-3
```

The answer is 2 but:

```
print(a.count('3'))
```

returns 3 as -3 is counted

How can I exclude the negatives?

My full code is:

```
a=input()
print(a.count('3'))
print(a.count('-3'))
```

With the input being:

```
[3,3,-3]
```

Comment: Inputing `[3,3,-3]` will return the string `"[3,3,-3]"`. You will need to convert the input to a list of you want this to work.

Comment: That "input" is not a valid python list. It's a string that *resembles* a list, but it's not. Python is not javascript (luckily).

Comment: @musicamante how do i convert it to a list?

Comment: @Daniil the real question is: why is that input like that? And, also, could it be any different? Should you account for other "styles" of input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `input` returns a string, not a list. You will need to convert it to a suitable format. Here is a way to do so.

```
a_string = input()
a = [int(x) for x in a_string.split(",")]

print(a.count(3))
```

This way you input has now been converted to a `list` of `int`.

### Input

```
3,3,-3
```

### Output

```
2
```

Comment: You forgot the last `]` I think

Answer (score 1):

you can use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
from ast import literal_eval

a = literal_eval(input())
# input is [3,3,-3]
print(a.count(3))
```

output:

```
2
```

with your input `[3,3,-3]` applying `literal_eval` you will get a list with numbers that are positive or negative according to the input and the count can be done base on your positive number `3`